# How to prevent Tkinter from opening multiple windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code sometimes opens only one window, sometimes 4 and sometimes 2. What am I doing wrong? I can not figure out what the problem is...

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import cv2
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

a = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(a, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1600)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1200)
ret, frame = vid.read()
if (ret==True):
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(cv2.resize(frame, (1000, 1000)) ), master=a)



def put_image():
    myimage = canvas.create_image(500,500,image = img, tag="img")
    
def func():
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        canvas.delete(myimage) #Deletes the rectangle
        print("worked")
    except:
        print("nope")

put_image()
func()
a.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, remove the `time.sleep(10)` and use `a.after(10*1000, func)` instead of just `func()`. Second of all, you need to add `global myimage` to the start of `put_image`, if you want the image to be deleted later. Third of all, I can't find any reason as to why it would open 4 windows. Are all of the windows `tkinter` or might it be that `cv2` opens some of the windows?

Comment: I know that this code is very "ugly", it was just some quick test but thank you for the suggestions. No all windows are from tkinter and I don't see any reason for this behaviour as well, I find it really confusing. Did something like that ever happen to you?

Comment: I tested your code as it is, and I also tested it using my suggestions. In both cases the result was only 1 window. I really can't find any reason for why you would see multiple windows. Please note that `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` wasn't working for me so I used `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` which is my camera. But I don't think that can cause the issue

Comment: Perhaps in this case, a video might help

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for this code to create more than one window unless something inside of `cv2.VideoCapture` does it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out on this. I did not see a reason either and maybe I didn't describe this well but the code also opens only one window for me but sometimes it will suddenly open a lot. I thought that there might be a mistake I did not see but as this doesn't seem to be the case, there might be a problem with the code I executed before. I just wanted to be sure I'm not blind for my own mistake. So Again, thank you and if someone posts something as Answer I'll accept.